# Share custom file using React Native

Tags: android, react-native, base64

I have a custom file something like `file.myext` which I create it using [`rn-fetch-blob`](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob):

`RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8')`

And I'm using [`react-native-share`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) to share the file,
I tried both:

```
Share.open({type: 'text/plain', url: 'file://'+path})
```

and

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(path, 'base64')
.then((data) => {
   Share.open({url: 'data:text/plain;base64,'+data})
})
```

but doesn't work, the second one share `.txt` file.

anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Might help, when I was also looking into this, using `react-native-fs` I was able to do:

```
          var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';
            RNFS.writeFile(path, 'test', 'utf8')
              .then(() => {
                console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
                Share.open({
                  url: 'file://' + path,
                })
                  .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    err && console.log(err);
                  });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);
              });
```